# Can't populate Select2 v4.x with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using the most recent version of select2 (version 4), I managed to make requests via AJAX and I already check that the responses are okay. However, the select is not populating its options with results found in a search. Perhaps I'm missing something but I don't know, here it is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#cliente").select2({
    //allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
      url: "<%= clientes_getclientes_path(format: 'json') %>",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data, params) {
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data
        return {
          results: data.clientes
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    //escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    theme: 'bootstrap'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code appears to be fine. Can you show us the result of your `clientes_getclientes_path(format: 'json')` ?

Comment: Url is ok `/clientes/getclientes.json`. Maybe you want the Response instead. If I write something like 'Bernardino' I get the following response:
`{"clientes":[{"cod_cte":"G0941","nom_cte":"AGRICOLA  DON BERNARDINO SPR DE RI"},{"cod_cte":"G1011","nom_cte":"AGRICOLA DON BERNARDINO, S.P.R. DE R.I."},{"cod_cte":"G1463","nom_cte":"BERNARDINO DIAZ ROMAN"},{"cod_cte":"EN0104","nom_cte":"BERNARDINO GARCIA GARCIA"}]}`

Comment: Can you rename the JSON fields or is it coming from external source? The solutions are different for each case. Basically your json should return objects that contain `id` and `text`.

Comment: Perhaps, because I created a controller to provide that json, but those fields are more meaningful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either rename your JSON so it'll return `id` instead of `cod_cte` and `text` instead of `nom_cte`, or (less efficient), use mapping:

```
return {
  results: $.map(data.clientes, function (obj) { return { id: obj.cod_cte, text: obj.nom_cte };})
};
```

Comment: Actually tried this before, but the problem I was mapping only `data` instead `data.clientes`.

Comment: why map could be less efficient ?

Comment: It's simply another action that won't be needed if the JSON was select2-compatible.

Comment: is there a way to send another parameter rather than "q"?